# Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

I had created a WCF service then i tested it, it was running successfully!
but now, when i test the service using WCF Test Client it raise the following error:

Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

IPublisher interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPublisher
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Server> GetAvailableServer();
}
```

PublisherService.svc Service:

```
 public class PublisherService : IPublisher
{

    public List<Server> GetAvailableServer()
    {
        try
        {
            AllChatEntities db = new AllChatEntities();
            List<Server> servers = (from s in db.Servers select s).ToList();
            return servers;
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
}
```

So, i had read some previous questions about this error in stackoverflow but there answers is not seems appropriate.

Comment: when i return a primetive type like a string the service is working successfully!

Comment: the error in details:
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Comment: Why did the other answers not seem appropriate?  Can you post the service and client config files - I have an idea of what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your comment (error in detail) I can suggest you to increase the max buffer size & MaxReceivedMessageSize in SvcConfigEditor (through VS command prompt or Wcf Test Client)

[image: WCF Configurator]